# Mysql Join to show all records with or without matching records

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One for employees and another for ratings. Some employees have been rated others not. I'm trying to list **all the employees with or without a rating value** and sort them from the highest rating.

```
emp table

empid empName
--------------
1     John
2     Alex
3     Peter
4     Mary

Ratings table

ratingid | customerid | ratingvalue | empid
---------------------------------------------
1         1             4             1
2         6             2             1
3         4             3             3
4         5             5             4
```

Expected output:

```
empid  | empName   | avgrating | ratingcount
---------------------------------------------
1         John             3             2
2         Alex             0             0
3         Peter            3             1
4         Mary             5             1
```

I tried

```
SELECT *, round(AVG(ratingvalue ), 2) as avgrating, count(empid) as ratingcount 
FROM emp LEFT JOIN ratings ON emp.empid = ratings.empid ORDER BY `avgrating`
DESC
```

That query doesn't produce the result I expect. It only gives me one row.

Thanks in advance

Comment: need group by to correctly show results or mySQL does strange things...

Comment: If you want a full data set, you should not use a LEFT join.  That will concentrate on just the table on the LEFT.  Try a crossjoin, or just lose the LEFT.

Comment: Still struggling? Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need group by and coalesce null values to 0.

```
SELECT EmpID, empName, 
  coalesce(round(AVG(ratingvalue ), 2),0) as avgrating, 
  coalesce(count(empid),0) as ratingcount 
FROM emp 
LEFT JOIN ratings 
  ON emp.empid = ratings.empid 
GROUP BY EmpID, EmpName
ORDER BY `avgrating`DESC
```

Comment: mySQL doesn't enforce the group by logic when using aggregates. Other RDMBS will throw an error, this just doesn't give you the correct data.. which if your not paying attention can be wrong. Be aware of that in future use!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
 select 
   e.id, e.name, 
   avg(coalesce(t1.rating,0)) average_rating, 
   count(coalesce(t1.rating,0)) count_rating 
 from 
(select '1' id, 'John' name union all
select '2' id, 'Alex' name union all
select '3' id, 'Peter' name union all
select '4' id, 'Mary' name) e


left join (select '1' id, '1' customer_id, '4' rating, '1' emp_id union all
select '2' id, '6' customer_id, '2' rating, '1' emp_id union all
select '3' id, '4' customer_id, '3' rating, '3' emp_id union all
select '4' id, '5' customer_id, '5' rating, '4' emp_id) t1 on
  t1.emp_id = e.id
group by 
 e.id, 
 e.name
```

I have just subbed out your tables for data. You can run this in mysql directly and it should give you want you want.